# Best practice create table or use ID in mysql in one table

Tags: mysql, database-design

I want to store many lists of users from forms. But i'm not sure what is the best practice about it.

I'm not sure if is better to create a mysql table for every list (CREATE table 'nameoflist') or better create 2 tables one for the names of the list and the other for each user with the ID of the first table (name of the list) to identificate from what list is.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If lists are structurally identical, there's no reason for multiple tables with the same schema. One table with a column that indicates type.

Answer (score 1):

Creating separate tables for identical lists is generally useless. The only situation it may be helpful is when you expect millions of rows in every list - then you would have a performance advantage of looking through smaller individual tables.